# Auto complete do JqueryUi

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

não estou conseguindo listar meu Json no autocomplete do jqueryUI.
No console do navegador eu vejo que ele está chamando mais não mostra na hora momento que aplico o append na LI.

```js
$(function(){
    var mostraLista = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
    $.get(mostraLista, function(response){
  var dados = response;
  for(var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++){
   var tudoJ = dados[i];
   console.log(tudoJ.name);
   $("<li>").text(tudoJ.email).appendTo(".ui-corner-all");
  }
 });

  $("#tags").autocomplete({
   source: mostraLista
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O autocomplete precisa de ter os dados já formatados. Se lhe passares uma array com o que precisas já vai funcionar. No exemplo em baixo mapeio os dados para criar uma array só com os nomes. E assim no autocomplete ele vai buscar e insere automáticamente o HTML necessário.

```
$(function() {
    var url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
    $.get(url, function(response) {
        var nomes = response.map(function(pessoa){
        return pessoa.name;
        })
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: nomes
        });
    });
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zskqf7hj/

Comment: Resolveu meu problema, mais fiquei com uma duvida.
como ele fez o append ?

Comment: @DiBoa o próprio plugin faz isso.